# Drawn objects missing after adding camera view

Tags: c#, opengl, view

so after implementing camera/ view to my scene, the objects that i was drawing have disappeared. before adding the camera my scene would draw 2 squares. from some testing i believe the cause of the issue to be `uView` in `gl_Position = vec4(vPosition, 1) * uModel * uView;` in the shader file. is this what is causing the issue or is it something else?

main file:

```
using OpenTK;
using System;
using OpenTK.Graphics;
using Labs.Utility;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;


namespace Labs.Lab2
{
    public class Lab2_2Window : GameWindow
    {
        public Lab2_2Window()
            : base(
                800, // Width
                600, // Height
                GraphicsMode.Default,
                "Lab 2_2 Understanding the Camera",
                GameWindowFlags.Default,
                DisplayDevice.Default,
                3, // major
                3, // minor
                GraphicsContextFlags.ForwardCompatible
            )
    {
    }

    private int[] mVBO_IDs = new int[2];
    private int mVAO_ID;
    private ShaderUtility mShader;
    private ModelUtility mModel;
    private Matrix4 mView;

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set some GL state
        GL.ClearColor(Color4.DodgerBlue);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.CullFace);

        mModel = ModelUtility.LoadModel(@"Utility/Models/lab22model.sjg");    
        mShader = new ShaderUtility(@"Lab2/Shaders/vLab22.vert", @"Lab2/Shaders/fSimple.frag");
        GL.UseProgram(mShader.ShaderProgramID);
        int vPositionLocation = GL.GetAttribLocation(mShader.ShaderProgramID, "vPosition");
        int vColourLocation = GL.GetAttribLocation(mShader.ShaderProgramID, "vColour");

        mVAO_ID = GL.GenVertexArray();
        GL.GenBuffers(mVBO_IDs.Length, mVBO_IDs);

        GL.BindVertexArray(mVAO_ID);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, mVBO_IDs[0]);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(mModel.Vertices.Length * sizeof(float)), mModel.Vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);           
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, mVBO_IDs[1]);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(mModel.Indices.Length * sizeof(float)), mModel.Indices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

        int size;
        GL.GetBufferParameter(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, BufferParameterName.BufferSize, out size);
        if (mModel.Vertices.Length * sizeof(float) != size)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Vertex data not loaded onto graphics card correctly");
        }

        GL.GetBufferParameter(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, BufferParameterName.BufferSize, out size);
        if (mModel.Indices.Length * sizeof(float) != size)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Index data not loaded onto graphics card correctly");
        }

        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(vPositionLocation);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(vPositionLocation, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 6 * sizeof(float), 0);
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(vColourLocation);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(vColourLocation, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 6 * sizeof(float), 3 * sizeof(float));


        mView = Matrix4.Identity;
        Vector3 eye = new Vector3(1.2f, 2.0f, -5.0f);
        Vector3 lookAt = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        Vector3 up = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
        mView = Matrix4.LookAt(eye, lookAt, up);

        int uView = GL.GetUniformLocation(mShader.ShaderProgramID, "uView");
        GL.UniformMatrix4(uView, true, ref mView);

        GL.BindVertexArray(0);

        base.OnLoad(e);

    }



    protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnRenderFrame(e);
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

        int uModelLocation = GL.GetUniformLocation(mShader.ShaderProgramID, "uModel"); //moved square to right of screen
        Matrix4 m1 = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(0.5f, 0, 0); //moved square to right of screen
        Matrix4 r1 = Matrix4.CreateRotationZ(0);

        Matrix4 final1 = m1 * r1; //combines translation and rotation - order matters

        GL.UniformMatrix4(uModelLocation, true, ref final1);

        GL.BindVertexArray(mVAO_ID);
        GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, mModel.Indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);

        Matrix4 r2 = Matrix4.CreateRotationZ(0);
        Matrix4 m2 = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(-0.5f, 0, 0); //draws second square on the left

        Matrix4 final2 = r2 * m2; //combines translation and rotation - order matters

        GL.UniformMatrix4(uModelLocation, true, ref final2);

        GL.BindVertexArray(mVAO_ID);
        GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, mModel.Indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);

        GL.BindVertexArray(0);
        this.SwapBuffers();
    }
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
        if (e.KeyChar == 'a')
        {
            mView = mView * Matrix4.CreateTranslation(1, 0, 0);
            int uView = GL.GetUniformLocation(mShader.ShaderProgramID, "uView");
            GL.UniformMatrix4(uView, true, ref mView);
        }
        if (e.KeyChar == 'd')
        {
            mView = mView * Matrix4.CreateTranslation(-1, 0, 0);
            int uView = GL.GetUniformLocation(mShader.ShaderProgramID, "uView");
            GL.UniformMatrix4(uView, true, ref mView);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
    {
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, 0);
        GL.BindVertexArray(0);
        GL.DeleteBuffers(mVBO_IDs.Length, mVBO_IDs);
        GL.DeleteVertexArray(mVAO_ID);
        mShader.Delete();
        base.OnUnload(e);
    }
}
}
```

shader file:

```
#version 330

uniform mat4 uModel;
uniform mat4 uView;

in vec3 vPosition;
in vec3 vColour;

out vec4 oColour;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vPosition, 1) * uModel * uView;
    oColour = vec4(vColour, 1);
}
```

Comment: It has to be `gl_Position = uView * uModel  * vec4(vPosition, 1);`

Comment: @Rabbid76 i tried your suggestion but nothing happened